# Setting observable statements in viewModel

Tags: knockout.js

In my knockoutjs view, I want to set some observable statements by code instead of declaring it in the html.

Lets say, in html I can do this:

```
<div data-bind="style: { color: someValue() >= 0 ? '' : 'red' }"></div>
```

Where someValue() is na observable in a viewModel. Whenever someValue() changes, the rule is executed and the color of the element is automatically changed. All ok, it works.

But I want to configure that rule in code, not in html.
I want something like this  (the concept is just a sample):

```
<div data-bind="style: style"></div>
<script>
var viewModel =
{
    style: someValue() >= 0 ? '' : 'red' //<-- how make it observable?
}
</script>
```

Noticed that is just evaluated and style will store '' or 'red'. Not what I want to acquire. I want this be evaluated as someValue() changes, super simple like the html way does.

Well, I don't know if the way is going to computeds, but as html mode is so easy, maybe there is a quick way to do this by code.

Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `ko.computed` and `ko.pureComputed` are for:

```js
var someValue = ko.observable(0);

// All observables used in a computed will trigger changes
var style = ko.computed(function() {
  return someValue() > 0 ? 'not-red' : 'red';
});

// Log if it is actually observable:
console.log(ko.isObservable(style));

// Log its initial value
console.log(style());

// Subscribe to changes in our computed
style.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
});

// Changing one of the computed's dependencies will result
// in the subscription being triggered and a log to console
someValue(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following in your view model.

```
    self = this;
    self.someValue = ko.observable(1); // default observable's value
    self.changeRed = function () {
        return someValue() >= 0 ? '' : 'red';
    };
```

Your HTML code will be as following.

```
<div data-bind="style: { color: changeRed() }"></div>
```

And whenever you updated your observable, e.g. call `self.someValue(-1);` in your view model, your browser will reflect the change.

**UPDATE**

I can't see your codebase, however if there is no specific reason to use inline styles, I would probably change this to use a CSS class.

Comment: This makes the html way and and viewModel way work different. I was looking to set "style: vmStyle", not "style: { prop: vmMethod }". Thanks anyway (I got the answer above)